# Prove (A closure) Complement=(A complement) Interior

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

Any Help would be much Appreciated.
I want to prove that in a metric space $(X,d)$ we have

$$X \setminus \overline{A} = \operatorname{int}(X \setminus A)$$

Where $x \in \operatorname{int}(A)$ iff $\exists r>0: B(x,r) \subseteq A$.
and 
$x \in \overline{A}$ iff there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ from $A$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$.

Comment: It depends on your definition of interior and closure. Please, write down these definitions. After doing that, you have to use nothing but DeMorgan's law.

Comment: Interior definition I use: A is the set of all interior points of A, x E A is an interior point of A if there Exists: Nest(x,r) subset of A. where r=radius.

Comment: Closure is: {x E A: there exists Xn with Xn tneding to x as n tends to infinity}

Comment: they are my definitions if you could please help

Comment: Learn a bit of $\Tex$

Comment: Crostul can you please help? you seem knowledgeable on the topic.

Comment: also i haven't heard of DeMorgan's law before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $x \in \operatorname{int}(X \setminus A)$.
This means that we have some $r>0$ such that $B(x,r) \subset X \setminus A$. 
We want to show that $x \notin \overline{A}$ so assume it is.
Then we'd have a sequence $a_n \in A$ such that $A_n \rightarrow x$. But by the definition of convergence, for some $N$ all $n \ge N$ lie in $B(x,r)$ and hence in $X\setminus A$. So e.g. $a_N \in A $ and $a_N \notin A$. Contradiction so $x \notin \overline{A}$.

The reverse inclusion is similar. Let $x \notin \overline{A}$ and suppose for a contradiction that $x \notin \operatorname{int}(X \setminus A)$.
Then for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have that $B(x,\frac{1}{n}) \nsubseteq X \setminus A$ (or it would be in that interior), so we can pick $a_n \in A \cap B(x, \frac{1}{n})$.
Standard arguments show that $a_n \rightarrow x$, as the $\frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0$. But his would show that $x \in \overline{A}$ contradiction, so $x \in \operatorname{int}(X \setminus A)$ after all.

Answer (score 0):

We want $(X-S)^0=X-\bar{S}$

$$x\in (X-S)^0\Longleftrightarrow\exists\text{ open }G,\,x\in G\subset (X-S)^0\subset X-S\Longleftrightarrow$$ $$\Longleftrightarrow\exists\text{ open }G,\,x\in G,\,G\cap S=\emptyset\Longleftrightarrow x\notin\bar{S}\Longleftrightarrow x\in X-\bar{S}$$

Answer (score 0):

According to the identity $\overline{A} = \text{int}(A)\cup\partial A$, one concludes the desired claim:
\begin{align*}
X\backslash\overline{A} = X\backslash(\text{int}(A)\cup\partial(A)) = \text{ext}(A) = \text{int}(X\backslash A)
\end{align*}